Width calculation in responsive web site
I am working on Project Landing Page of freecodecamp site. Following is my code


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    
    border: 1px solid black;
}


main {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 4rem;
}




#features {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 28%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#video {
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    text-align: end;
    width: 950px;
    margin: 2em auto 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

footer > a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

footer > p {
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 952px) {
    footer {
        width: auto;
    }

    
}
    <main>

          <section id="features">
            <div>
                <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
                <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
                <br><br>
            </div>

            

            <div>
                <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
                <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
                <br><br>
            </div>


            <div>
                <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
                <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
                <br><br>
            </div>

          </section>

          <section>
            <iframe width="560" id="video" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/y8Yv4pnO7qc?si=6TmQlZHbZ_rJsacf&amp;controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </section>

         
    </main>

    <footer>

        <a href="#">Privacy</a>
        <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>

        <p>Copyright 2016, Original Trombones</p>
    </footer>



Now, I have to make this site responsive. So using dev tools, I change the viewport size. If I look at the footer element, I get following parameters in Opera browser when I set viewport size to 956px
viewport = 956px
footer width = 950px
body border = 1 + 1 = 2px
body width = 941.6px
footer margin-right = -10px

And I also get a horizontal scroll bar at this viewport width. Now, for the same viewport width, I get following parameters in Chrome browser
viewport = 956px
footer width = 950px
body border = 1 + 1 = 2px
body width = 939.2px
footer margin-right = -12.4px

And again a horizontal scroll bar. Now, my question is how do these numbers add up ? If there is a horizontal scroll bar, viewport width should be less than footer width since footer is overflowing body border. I am confused.

what do you mean? 942px body width whily having box-sizing: border: box means the content width is 942px - (2 x 1ps border thickness) = 940px content width for the body. The footer is set to auto which means that it will take all available content width (940px). margin-right: -10px will make the footer by 10px larger 940px + 10px = 950px. Same for the other calculation. The difference is just how they calculate the border.

But if footer width is 940px, then why is it going outside body border ?

Because of the negative margin

I am not sure if I got your question correct, but if you check the margin-left you have in your code, it is pushing the video to the side and since you have a fixed width for your video frame, this makes the content grow and causes some issues on the size of your container.
If you can provide more information on your issue or even a visual clue of the expected result it could help to get a more accurate answer.
